# Activity goes to the background after being reordered to front using FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have two activities A & B. From activity A, B is started which in it's `onCreate()` reorders A to front using `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`. No activity transition occurs and appears as if B was never started. This is the intended behaviour and it works.

The problem that I'm facing is, sometimes, after A is reordered, A is sent to the background and if a previous activity was present below A in the activity stack, that activity is brought to the front.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @Chitrang I don't remember. It was very long ago.